# how to extract the header title in Jquery Mobile if only the URL is available?

Tags: jquery, hash, jquery-mobile

I'm storing the link to a page and later need to retrieve the page's header title.

So I basically have this:

```
http://www.some.mobi/demo/1/index.html#features
```

and need to find out using jquery, what the header h3 title is?

Any idea how to accomplish this when only the absolute URL is available?

Thanks for helping!

**EDIT**:

A JQM page would look like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="some">
  <div data-role="header">
      <h3>I need this</h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

This will be pulled in if I fire a link with the above URL.

Comment: a title will be something like this:  <h3>some page</h3>. This is sitting inside the page header <div data-role="header"></div>. I need to extract it, in order to put it on a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work, Live Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/LSGn4/4/

JS:

```
var theTitle = $("div:jqmData(role='header')").children('h3').html();
alert('Title: '+theTitle);
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="some">
  <div data-role="header">
      <h3>I need this</h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
      Page 1
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
      Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah. more or less. I'm using obj = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ); and then checking for obj.hash or obj.filename. Not perfect, but fits my need. Your solution works fine, too, but you will need to have the page loaded, whereas I was looking for a way create a page object from the URL and then extract the header from it (using your answer for example) before anything is loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want load the content of the external page and query it to get the header value,
This may be a good start..

http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with my hobby project [pulljson.com](http://pulljson.com) ,a cross-domain parser solution like in [post by dotnetwala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145690/805366):

GET JSONP example:

```
http://www.pulljson.com/jquery?site=http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html&selector=find('%23two').children('div').children('p')&callback=?
```

See usage example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/santeriv/PQ8Jx/1/ which is cloned from http://jsfiddle.net/LSGn4/4/